# Probability quiz question

Tags: probability

3 machines b1 b2 and b3 are made. B1 makes up 35% of machines made b2 represents 30% and b3 35%. With b1 being defective 2% of the time, b2 "3% and b3 2%.

A) what is the probability of a randomly selected machine being defective?

I said .7 because 2+3+2

B) what is the probability of a machine being b1 given it is defective?

I said p(b1|d) = .2/.7

Is this wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your main problem was interpreting what "b1 being defective 2% of the time" meant.

> > 3 machines b1 b2 and b3 are made. B1 makes up 35% of machines made b2 represents 30% and b3 35%. With b1 being defective 2% of the time, b2 "3% and b3 2%.

This means $2\%$ of $B_1$ machines are defective, *not* that $2\%$ of all machines are defective and $B_1$.  The later is correctly obtained by:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(B_1\cap D) & = \mathsf P(B_1)\cdot\mathsf P(D\mid B_1) \\ & = (35\%)(2\%) \\ & = 0.70\%\end{align}$$

> > A) what is the probability of a randomly selected machine being defective?
>
> I said .7 because 2+3+2

You do need to add the proportions of machines which are defective and of each type. However, as above, those aren't the right numbers to add.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(D) & = \mathsf P(B_1\cap D)+\mathsf P(B_2\cap D)+\mathsf P(B_3\cap D) \\ & = (35\%)(2\%)+(30\%)(3\%)+(35\%)(2\%) \\ & = 2.3\%\end{align}$$

> > B) what is the probability of a machine being b1 given it is defective?
>
> I said p(b1|d) = .2/.7

Again, you seem aware what to do, but are just using the wrong numbers.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(B_1\mid D) & = \frac{\mathsf P(B_1\cap D)}{\mathsf P(D)} \\ & = \frac{ (35\%)(2\%)}{2.3\%} \\ & \approx 30.4\%\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Law of Total Probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Statement) for part (a) and [Bayes' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Introduction) for part (b).

For part (a) you need to take into account that different machine types have different probabilities of being defective, and a randomly selected machine is not equally likely to be $B_1$, $B_2$, or $B_3$.

For example, the probability that a randomly selected machine is defective given that it is of type B1 is $P(B_1)P(D|B_1) = 0.35 \times 0.02$.

The total probability is $P(D) = P(B_1)P(D|B_1) + P(B_2)P(D|B_2) + P(B_3)P(D|B_3)$

For part (b) you need to notice that you have $P(D|B_1)$ but you are asked for $P(B_1|D)$. Bayes' theorem says that

$$P(B_1|D) = \frac{P(D|B_1)P(B_1)}{P(D)}$$

You are given the probabilities in the numerator, and $P(D)$ in the denominator is from part (a).

Answer (score 0):

For A, it should be clear that the answer is between $2\%$ and $3\%$  For this part, you can lump the b1 and b3 machines together and say they make up $70\%$ of the volume with a $2\%$ defective rate.  You should find the weighted average of the defective rates.

For B, calculate the total expected number of defective machines out of $100$, and the total number of defective b1 machines out of $35$  Dividing gives you the fraction of defective machines that are b1

Answer (score 0):

A) $p(defective)=p(defective|b1)p(b1)+p(defective|b2)p(b2)+p(defective|b3)p(b3)=.02*0.35+0.03*0.3+0.02*0.35=0.023$

B)

$p(b1|defective)=\frac{p(defective|b1)p(b1)}{p(defective)} = \frac{0.02*0.35}{0.023}=0.304$